# VB Select Statement

Tags: vba

I am in the process of converting a VB application to C#. I came across this select statement and am confused why it is even necessary. Isn't the 'case else' just like the default in a C# switch statement?

```
Select Case dbp.DbType
 Case Else
 dbcmd.CommandText &= " [" & dbp.ParameterName & "]='" & dbp.Value.ToString().Replace("'", "''") & "'"
End Select
```

Comment: Removed select-statement tag as it can be confused with `sql` select

Comment: Looks like it was included to handle some configuration setting which was never implemented. Leaving it makes it clear that that's somewhere to pay attention to if they ever got around to implementing it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're correct, it's completely unnecessary. In the absence of all other `Case` clauses, this code translates to:

```
dbcmd.CommandText &= " [" & dbp.ParameterName & "]='" & dbp.Value.ToString().Replace("'", "''") & "'"
```

Answer (score 1):

The `Select Case`code you posted is redundant . As long ass there are no other `Case ConditionHere`, the line `dbcmd...` will always be executed, i.e. the case statement can be removed.

Answer (score 1):

Correct; the `CASE ELSE` statement in VBA is like the `default` statement for a C# switch.

`CASE ELSE` and `default` will both execute if no other conditions are met; I assume there is more to your VBA code, since a stand-alone `CASE ELSE` doesn't make much sense.